# Intellij Building Using Ant

Tags: ant, intellij-idea

Thanks to Android-Studio I am now trying to use the IntelliJ Idea for my non-Android projects.

I've installed the latest version of the Community version of IntelliJ (12.1.4).  I've created a simple test project with a few classes a JavaCC grammar definition to try things out.  From the command line the ant script builds the project just fine.

From an Ant building point of view I have everything configured just fine.

But I haven't quite got things working within IntelliJ. I do have that part of the ant script being executed to update the generated Java source from the grammar file. I can see in the logs that the ant task to run javaCC is called each time, just before the "Make".

But IntelliJ doesn't "see" that part of the tree.

In "File -> Project Structure -> Modules" I've configured the source paths thus:

```
<project-root>
    build
        classes     <- Excluded
        java        <- Sources
    libs
    src
        main
            java    <- Sources
            javacc  <- Place where grammar file lives.
        test
            data
            java    <- Test sources
```

And in the sources list it reports the following:

```
Source Folders
    src/main/java
    build/java

Test Source Folder
    src/test/java
```

In `build/java` are all the sources generated from running JavaCC (in the appropriate package sub-directory).  So why is IntelliJ not picking them up?

As always thanks for any help.

Steve

**UPDATE**

My computer runs Linux, Debian to be precise, and JavaCC has installing into /usr/share/java.

1). Create a new project "Test"

2). Create a new directory off the project root: `javacc`.

3). Added the following file `Test.jj` to `javacc`

```
options {
    STATIC = false;
}

PARSER_BEGIN(Test)

package com.example;

import java.io.StringReader;

public class Test {

    private boolean mIsBaseball = false;

    public Test(final String text) {
        this(new StringReader(text));
    }
}
PARSER_END(Test)

TOKEN: { <DOT:          "."> }
TOKEN: { <SLASH:        "/"> }

void dummy():
{
}
{
    <SLASH> <DOT>
}
```

4). Added the following ant script `build.xml` to the project base.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" standalone="no"?>
<project name="test" default="all" basedir=".">

    <property name="pkg.name" value="test"/>

    <property name="dir.src.java" value="${basedir}/src/"/>
    <property name="dir.src.javacc" value="${basedir}/javacc"/>
    <property name="dir.test.java" value="${basedir}/out/src"/>
    <property name="dir.class" value="${basedir}/out/Test"/>

    <target name="grammar">

        <mkdir dir="${basedir}"/>
        <mkdir dir="${basedir}/out/"/>
        <mkdir dir="${dir.test.java}"/>
        <mkdir dir="${dir.test.java}/com"/>
        <mkdir dir="${dir.test.java}/com/example"/>

        <javacc
                target="${dir.src.javacc}/Test.jj"
                outputdirectory="${dir.test.java}/com/example"
                javacchome="/usr/share/java/"
                debugparser="true" />

    </target>

    <target name="compile" depends="grammar">

        <mkdir dir="${dir.class}"/>

        <javac destdir="${dir.class}"
               includeantruntime="false"
               debug="on">
            <compilerarg value="-Xlint:-path"/>
            <src path="${dir.src.java}"/>
            <src path="${dir.test.java}"/>
        </javac>
    </target>

</project>
```

5). In the "Ant Build" window register the new build script.

6). Run the `gammar` target from the "And Build" window.  You should see some new Java classes in `${PROJECT_BASE}/out/src`.

7). In "Project Structure -> Modules -> Paths" select "Use module output path" and deselect the "Exclude output paths"

6). In "Project Structure -> Modules -> Sources" add "out -> src" as a source directory.  Both `src` and `out/scr` should be the only listings.

8). Edit `Main.java` to the following:

```
package com.example;

import com.example.Test;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Test test = new Test("/.");
            test.dummy();

        } catch (Throwable cause) {
            cause.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see the generated source is not visible (well I can on mine).

9). From the command line you can compile and run things quite happily.

```
$ ant
$ java -cp out/Test com.example.Main
Call:   dummy
  Consumed token: <"/" at line 1 column 1>
  Consumed token: <"." at line 1 column 2>
Return: dummy
$
```

Comment: Does IDEA see the sources after `File` | `Synchronize`?

Comment: Hi CC.  No it doesn't!

Comment: Please share a sample project that will reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi CC.  I've added a simple example above (under Update).  BTW my version of IntelliJ is 12.1.4 (#IC-129.713, built on Jun 10, 2013).  Many thanks for you help in this.

Comment: It would be easier if you just zip and share the project directory via some file exchange service (dropbox, google drive, skydrive, etc).

Comment: A compressed tar file is now on: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0Bw1LYEKJi2sBZU1aVEp6dWRDc2M/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Your sources are generated into the output directory that is ignored by the IDE. Change the `javacc` task configuration to `outputdirectory="${dir.test.java}/com/example"` and it will work fine.

Comment: Hi CC. Thanks for look at this for me.  `outputdirectory` is set to `${dir.test.java}/com/example`.  Did you change `dir.test.java` to somewhere different?  I pointed it back into my "source" area so it works, but this isn't the solution I want - generated source should not be in the same part of the tree as "real" source.

Comment: It was just an example, create another source folder not under output, or you can even have it in another module and then make your main module [depend on the module with the generated sources](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-module-dependencies-and-libraries.html).

Comment: Hi @Dobbo , how can i add jj file to javacc in intellij (step 3) ?